# How do I turn a ToString value into a &str at compile time?

Tags: rust, constants

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to create a `const … &str` from a `const T` where `T : ToString`?

---

I like to provide default values when I use [`clap`](https://docs.rs/clap/). However, `clap` needs the [`default_value`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) as `&str`, not as a primitive type:

```
pub fn default_value(self, val: &'a str) -> Self
```

Therefore, I cannot use a previously defined `const` if it is not a `&str`:

```
use clap::{App, Arg};

/// The application's default port.
pub const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT : u16 = 12345;

fn main () {
    let matches = App::new(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"))
        .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
        .arg(Arg::with_name("port")
             .short("p")
             .value_name("PORT")
             .default_value(DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT) // < error here
        ).get_matches();
     …
}
```

The workaround is to use a `&str` instead:

```
/// The application's default port.
pub const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT : u16 = 12345;

// Not public, since implementation detail.
const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR : &str = "12345";

fn main () {
    let matches = App::new(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"))
        .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
        .arg(Arg::with_name("port")
             .short("p")
             .value_name("PORT")
             .default_value(DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR)
        ).get_matches();
     …
}
```

However, the two constants can get easily out of sync:

```
/// The application's default port.
pub const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT : u16 = 4579;

const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR : &str = "12345"; // whoops
```

Therefore, I'd like to generate the latter from the former by some magic function or macro:

```
/// The application's default port.
pub const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT : u16 = 4579;

const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR : &str = magic!(DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT);
```

**Note:** Since [`std::string::ToString::to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) isn't `const`, it's out of scope but would provide a workaround in main, e.g.

```
let port_string = DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT.to_string();
let matches = App::new(env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"))
    .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
    .arg(Arg::with_name("port")
         .short("p")
         .value_name("PORT")
         .default_value(&port_string)
    ).get_matches();
```

But that's not really ergonomic either.

Is there any standard macro or function that I'm missing, or is there no language-defined way yet to provide that functionality?

Comment: Why `default_value(&DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT.to_string())` is not ergonomic? This is the way to go. BTW, you could use [structopt](https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt) that is an ergonomic wrapper to clap.

Comment: @Boiethios that value doesn't live long enough, since the temporary gets dropped (`error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed`). That's because the `default_value` expects a `&'a string`, where the lifetime `'a` stems from `Arg` and ultimately ends up in `ArgMatches`.

Comment: @Boiethios Just a small remark on `structopt`/`clap`: `clap` is the motivation for the question, but I'm more interested in a generic, not necessarily `clap`-oriented solution like your `DefaultParam` struct.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I don't understand why the code in my comment has not its lifetime inferred right, tho. Do you compile it with the 2018 edition?

Comment: @Boiethios see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6482855edcde948591235eb84374e00. You need to use actually use `matches`, otherwise you won't encounter the error (see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82f772541f08a0813868cf53b02a82fd for a variant without an error, since `matches` is unused). As far as I can see, the lifetimes are inferred fine, and the temporary string just doesn't live long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a macro to define the port integer and string at the same time using `stringify!`:

```
macro_rules! define_port {
    ($port:expr) => {
        pub const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT : u16 = $port;
        const DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR : &str = stringify!($port);
    }
}

define_port!(4579);

fn main() {
    println!("{}:{}", DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT, DEFAULT_LISTENER_PORT_STR);
}
```

Or, if you want a more generic one:

```
pub struct DefaultParam<T> {
    value: T,
    name: &'static str,
}

macro_rules! define {
    ( $name:ident : $t:ty = $val:expr ) => {
        pub const $name: DefaultParam<$t> = DefaultParam {
            value: $val,
            name: stringify!($val),
        };
    }
}

define!(PORT: u32 = 1234);

fn main() {
    println!("{} has the value: {}", PORT.name, PORT.value);
}
```

Comment: Heh. I was halfway there but tried to define a macro that returns a pair instead of two values. It didn't occur to me to define both in the macro itself (still new to macros). Is it possible to create the `_STR` variant from the normal variant and make the macro more generic, e.g. `define_option! { ($id:ident, $t:ty, $e:expr) => pub const $id : $t = $e; const MAGIC!($id) : &str = stringify!($e); }`?

Comment: @Zeta Not with a regular macro (at least in stable Rust). With a procedural one, this is ok.

Comment: @Zeta You can do that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=aec33a9f4ab73335d5aaad94d1d34330

Comment: @Boiethios excellent alternative answer. Feel free to post it, so that I can provide an upvote.